# Python - Get sum of pair in a list which is greater than a value with no index being used in multiple pairs

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem which requires me to find sum of pairs in a list. The pair indices have to be unique i.e no single index should be in multiple pairs. 
For example -

```
my_list = [1,1,2,3,4,5]
sum_greater_than_or_equal_to = 5
```

here, I have a sorted list and want to find all pairs where the sum is greater than or equal to 5. So, 
I am able to solve this problem in O(n^2) by making another loop over to find the pairs. The pairs without using an index in multiple pairs are -

```
output = [(1,4),(1,5),(2,3)]
```

is there another, more efficient way to do this?
without having to create two loops?

**EDIT -** people are mentioning answers which include values - `[(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5)]` But I want that if the index of the list is already used in a pair it cannot be used again.

Comment: what happened to the output `[(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5)]` ?

Comment: @K.Menyah all those indexes are already used right? I have explicitly mentioned in the question that each index should only be used once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will generate one possible combination of such pairs:

```
my_list = [1,1,2,3,4,5]

def find_pairs(arr, limit):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    res = []

    start = 0
    end = len(arr) - 1

    while start < end:
        if arr[start] + arr[end] >= limit:
            res.append((arr[start], arr[end]))
            end -= 1
        start += 1

    return res

print find_pairs(my_list, 5) # [(1, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

With the given test set solution `[(3,4), (2,5)]` would also be valid answer.

Comment: it could be but I want all the pairs

Comment: What do you mean by all pairs? If you can use any index only once there will be multiple valid answers with the given input. For example pairs `(3, 4)` and `(1, 4)` are mutually exclusive since value `4` appears only once in the input.

Comment: All pairs means the maximum number of pairs possible in the list with value greater than sum and with each index appearing only once.

Comment: Example code provides one such solution, i.e. it's impossible for any other solution to yield more pairs.

Comment: That example is made up by me and I know that was the maximum number of solutions possible. I am looking for a solution that could be generically implemented across such problems.

Comment: Example code can be generically used for all such problems. But imagine a scenario where `my_list = [1, 2, 4]` and `limit = 5`. With all information given so far `[(1, 4)]` and `[(2, 4)]` would be equally valid solutions.

Comment: yes, in that case any of the solutions would be valid.

Comment: In that case the example code fulfills your criteria since it will generate a solution with maximum number of pairs. There might be other solutions with same amount of pairs though,